# Python: Post Request with image files

Tags: python, post, request, urllib2, urllib

I have a server and I am trying to build a post request to get the data back. I think one way to achieve this is to add the parameters in the header and make the request. But I am getting few errors that I don't understand well enough to go forward.

Html Form

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  </head>
  <body>
     <form method="POST" action="http://some.server.com:61235/imgdigest" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        quality:<input type="text" name="quality" value="2"><br>
        category:<input type="text" name="category" value="1"><br>
        debug:<input type="text" name="debug" value="1"><br>
        image:<input type="file" name="image"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Python code: **I have edited the question based on the answer**

```
import urllib, urllib2
import base64

if __name__ == '__main__':
    page = 'http://some.site.com:61235/'
    with open("~/image.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    raw_params = {'quality':'2','category':'1','debug':'0', 'image': encoded_image}
    params = urllib.urlencode(raw_params)
    request = urllib2.Request(page, params)
    request.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
    page = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    info = page.info()
```

Errors:

```
    page = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, the image needs to be an image, not a string.  I would suggest trying out requests, instead of using urllib, urllib2.  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 5):

Add a this header:

```
request.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
```

Also, the image parameter you're sending is a string, not the contents of the image file. You need to b64 encode it

```
import base64

with open("image.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

then use `encoded_image` instead of '`~/image.jpg`' in `raw_params`

Comment: So I should add it to the header after  request = urllib2.Request(page, params)?

Comment: make sure the url you're using in your python code is exactly the same as action attribute in the html form.  Looks like you're adding '.html' in python.

Comment: ok, but notice how the url is still not the same, in python you have: 
page = 'http://some.site.com:61235/'
and in html you have:
...<form method="POST" action="http://some.server.com:61235/imgdigest"...
Python is missing the /imgdigest part